# Curl Requests Params inside url

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have an API, where all important Parameter like ID, category is in the Request's URL and not as payload. What would be the smartest and recommended way to solve this?

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://api.otto.market/v2/products?sku=SOME_STRING_VALUE&productReference=SOME_STRING_VALUE&category=SOME_STRING_VALUE&brand=SOME_STRING_VALUE&page=SOME_INTEGER_VALUE&limit=SOME_INTEGER_VALUE' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer REPLACE_BEARER_TOKEN'
```

What I did till now

```
def example(content_type: str, cache_control: str, grand_type:str, client_id:str):

    endpoint = website.BASE_URL
    header_content = {
        'Content-Type': (f'{content_type}'),
        'Cache-Control': (f'{cache_control}')
    }
    data_content = {
        'grant_type': (f'{grand_type}'),
        'client_id': (f'{client_id}')
    }
    response = requests.get(url= endpoint, headers=header_content, data=data_content, verify=False)
    return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests.get` has optional parameter `params` where you might deliver `dict`, consider following simple example

```
import requests
parameters = {"client":"123","product":"abc","category":"a"}
r = requests.get("https://www.example.com",params=parameters)
print(r.url)  # https://www.example.com/?client=123&product=abc&category=a
```

For further discussion read [Passing Parameters In URLs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)

Answer (score 1):

The curl request that you posted in python would be:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer REPLACE_BEARER_TOKEN',
}

params = {
    'sku': 'SOME_STRING_VALUE',
    'productReference': 'SOME_STRING_VALUE',
    'category': 'SOME_STRING_VALUE',
    'brand': 'SOME_STRING_VALUE',
    'page': 'SOME_INTEGER_VALUE',
    'limit': 'SOME_INTEGER_VALUE',
}

response = requests.get('https://api.otto.market/v2/products', params=params, headers=headers)
```

Insert your variables as required.